# javascript submits form even if return false

Tags: javascript, ajax, form-submit

I have a form with an action with an external URL with method post

```
<form name="myform" id="myform" action="externalurl.com" mehtod="post">
</form>
```

At the bottom of the page, I have my javascript tags as bellow and the on form submit I have a call that is made to a JsonResult, through Ajax, in the controller.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

$('form#myform').submit(function () {
    var FirstName = $("#FirstName").val();
    var LastName = $("#LastName").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/umbraco/Surface/CheckoutMain/RegisterUser?FirstName=" + FirstName + "&LastName=" + LastName,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        success: function (response) {
            debugger
            if (response == "Yes") {
                return true;
            }
            else if (response == "RequiredFields") {
                alert("Please make sure all required fields are filled in.")
                return false;
            }
            else if (response == "No") {
                alert(response + "Please contact us!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    })
});
</script>
```

I'm just not sure why it submits before I even return a response to the ajax call.

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Here also the code in my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult RegisterUser(string FirstName, string LastName)
    {
        if (FirstName == "" || LastName == "" )
        {
            return Json("RequiredFields", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {
            return Json("Yes", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        return Json("No", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Also if I return a No it will still post and if I put a breakpoint in the above code and step through I can see that the site has already redirected to the external URL. (I hope this makes sense).

If anyone has any advice I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$.ajax` is asynchronous, so anything the `success` handler returns will be ignored; by that time, the `submit` handler function will have completed (and will have returned `undefined`, not `false`).

Because you don't know whether the form can be submitted until after the response comes back, you should `return false` *regardless*, and then, if the response is OK, submit the form manually, otherwise don't submit the form (and just display the error):

```
$('#myform').submit(function() {
  var FirstName = $("#FirstName").val();
  var LastName = $("#LastName").val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/umbraco/Surface/CheckoutMain/RegisterUser?FirstName=" + FirstName + "&LastName=" + LastName,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    success: (response) => {
      if (response == "Yes") {
        this.submit();
      } else if (response == "RequiredFields") {
        alert("Please make sure all required fields are filled in.")
      } else if (response == "No") {
        alert(response + "Please contact us!");
      }
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

You might also note that because IDs in a document are (or *should be*) unique, feel free to just use the ID selector (`'#myform'`), no need to prefix it with `form` as well.

Comment: Thank you so much for that! It worked flawlessly. I learned something new today and will remember this going forward! Thank you I will take the prefix out.

Answer (score 0):

Your form submits because the HTML already causes a submit.

You can use [event.preventDefault()](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) to prevent that.

```
...
$('form#myform').submit(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
...
```